# Recover a chunk of compressed data from SD card

Tags: data-recovery, sd-card

I split a tar.bzip file in 3.5GB chunks and stored each chunk in a different SD card. After copying the data to all cards, I inserted one by one and opened it to verify that the file was there, then I removed the card safely.

Now I'm copying the data back, but one of the cards shows no files. It has the correct name, but no files appear. I've retrieved all other chunks with no problems.

What can I do to recover the missing data from the problematic card? Is there a certain location where the file should be?

`dmesg` right after inserting it:

```
[12789.690546] ntfs: volume version 3.1.
[12789.718682] ntfs: (device sdb1): ntfs_lookup_inode_by_name(): Directory index record with vcn 0x0 is corrupt.  Corrupt inode 0x5.  Run chkdsk.
[12789.718688] ntfs: (device sdb1): check_windows_hibernation_status(): Failed to find inode number for hiberfil.sys.
[12789.718690] ntfs: (device sdb1): load_system_files(): Failed to determine if Windows is hibernated.  Mounting read-only.  Run chkdsk.
[12789.772944] ntfs: (device sdb1): ntfs_lookup_inode_by_name(): Directory index record with vcn 0x0 is corrupt.  Corrupt inode 0x5.  Run chkdsk.
[12789.772953] ntfs: (device sdb1): ntfs_lookup(): ntfs_lookup_ino_by_name() failed with error code 5.
[12789.835735] ntfs: (device sdb1): ntfs_readdir(): Directory index record with vcn 0x0 is corrupt.  Corrupt inode 0x5.  Run chkdsk.
[12789.835982] ntfs: (device sdb1): ntfs_readdir(): Directory index record with vcn 0x0 is corrupt.  Corrupt inode 0x5.  Run chkdsk.
```

Comment: You can try file recover software of your choice but based on the error the filesystem is corrupt.

Comment: Try using Piriform Recuva (assuming your on Windows?)